# How to summarize overlapping time intervals on a time range efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, intervals

I have a large dictionary with events (say category a,b or c) that have a start_time and end_time during a day. The date of the interval of the timestamps can vary when it passes midnight. But with a maximum of two dates.
Example:

```
{
'event1': { 
   start_time: 04/05/2016, 04:23:11,
   end_time: 04/05/2016, 04:35:52,
   type: 'a'}
}
```

I'd like to visualize the concurrent number of categories during the day: 00:00 to 23:59. Say at 08:01 there are 43 category 'a' events, and 22 category b events simultaneously. To do this I want to summarize the concurrent number of events for each minute of the day.

I've set up a working example, but it inefficient and thus slow.

1. I've created a pandas.date_range for every minute of the day and set it as the index of an empty dataframe.
2. Then I loop over every event and extract the start & end times of the event and create a pandas.Interval object between the to times.
3. I loop through all the minutes of the day, and conditionally check if the minute falls in the interval. If so, count +1 for the specific event.
4. Repeat for all the events

```
zero_data = np.zeros(shape=(1440, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(zero_data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], index=pd.date_range( start='01/01/2019, 00:00', end='01/01/2019, 23:59', freq='1min'))

for k,v in dict:
  ... 'extract the event times' ..
  interval = pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp(start_time), pd.Timestamp(end_time))
  for minute in df.index:
     if minute in interval:
         df.loc[minute, event] = df.loc[minute, event] + 1
```

Some problems that arise:

- pd.date_range() and pd.Timestamp(start_of_day) always keep a date which is problematic due to the change in date overnight makes comparing difficult (a fugly solution of changing to a fixed date for both interval and daterange solved that)
- Because for every event I iterate 1440 times (the minutes of the day) it becomes painfully slow

I'm sure this can be done more elegant and quicker. Joining directly instead of iterating, using datetime functions more efficient. I just don't know how. Any advice?

Added example output: 
[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the expected output.

Comment: @Trenton_M, I've included the expected output.

Comment: @Nijhuis Sorry, I meant of the transformed DataFrame.

Comment: @Trenton_M the dataframe isn't really transformed. It has an index with minute increments for the whole day and three columns with values.